# Is PHP up and functioning properly

Tags: php

Is there a way to verify that PHP 5  is functioning properly on  Linux CENTOS. Is there a default address to check if php 5  is up and running

Comment: Do you have a web server installed?

Comment: No. You just stick a .php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a site's document root somewhere and hit that file in a browser. If you want to check command line, then `php -i` would do.

Comment: ^^ it is possible that command line php is working but it its not for the webserver and visa versa

Comment: Yes I have apache installed

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not "up" as it is not a service or similar. 
To verify that PHP is installed, open a terminal and type:

```
PHP -v
```

Should output something like:

```
PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2013 18:23:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Then you know that PHP is working.

To use PHP through a browser you need a webserver such as Apache.

Comment: Actually that depends if you are running PHP-FPM or not. In that situation PHP could be Up/Down if the FPM Process was not started or had become corrupted by some random situation.

Comment: THANK YOU I KNOW it is installed properly

Comment: Diemuzi - True, but one could argue that then you are not running PHP, but PHP-FPM. And yes i know i made bold statement. And to the unknown user: Thank you for the all caps.  Being shouted at is always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From command line/terminal, try this

```
php -v
```

Or

```
php -i
```

Answer (score 0):

If Apache is running (check by using a browser to go to apache address), then try this to see if php is running:

```
vi /var/www/info.php

<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Call that file in a browser (e.g. `http://ipapacheruns/info.php`), it could be (e.g. `http://localhost/info.php`):

Comment: Thanks I now know that PHP is working properly